# typo3 v9.5 - Powermail and export as csv issue

Tags: typo3, powermail

I use powermail for newsletter campaigns however i have a question, non-admin backend users can't add new columns before exporting data to csv.

When we are on the mail listing page of powermail and we click on "extended export settings", the right column with additional fields are not available, whereas they are available with an admin account.

How can I authorize non-admin users to add these additional fields?

I tried to found some config to allow it with typoscript but I didn't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your editors do not have permission to view these fields.

EXT:powermail is checking this in [`Resources/Private/Partials/Module/Export.html`](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Resources/Private/Partials/Module/Export.html) by an own ViewHelper:

```
{vh:condition.isBackendUserAllowedToViewField(table:'tx_powermail_domain_model_mail',field:'hidden')}
```

So, you need to allow some of the 'exclude'-fields for a backendusergroup these users belong to.
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/UserManagement/GroupPermissions/Index.html#allowed-excludefields